# How to make text DOM element appear on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to get the text after 'Search results for:' to appear on Google Analytics depending on what users searched for. For example, in this case, it should be 'Coffee, Lemon, Lime, Original' to appear on Google Analytics. Could you please show me? Thanks so much for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbFe6.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJRyz.png)

```html
<div class="cocktail-search__search-text">
<h3>Search results for: <br class="hide-portrait"><span>"Coffee, Lemon, Lime, Original"</span>
</h3> <div><h2>0 results - What is this whisk-ardry...</h2> 
<div class="cocktail-search__no-result-content"><p></p></div></div></div>
```

TT
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al5iJ.png

Comment: Hi Ramon, Thanks for your comment. This is the HTML code https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al5iJ.png. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please insert your html as text in the body of the question, in a neat code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the following function as a custom JS variable or set up a DOM-Element variable with "CSS-Selector" as selecting method an "br.hide-portrait" as selector.

```
function(){
  return document.querySelector('br.hide-portrait').innerText;
}
```

I always recommend not to use a JS var when possible.

Comment: Hello Ramon - Thanks for your response. If I use DOM-element in the GTM, should I use the 'hide-portrait' class in the code? Thanks